# Copy/paste in edit mode in Blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, workflow

Normally, I would agree that copy/paste is not necessary with the duplicate functionality (shift+d), but in this case, I think I have a legitimate reason to ask it.

I am working on a game that detects continuous pieces of same-material mesh to perform specific things with them. So now I have a mesh body where I need to bevel some edges (for aesthetic reasons) into new faces and change the material. I need these new faces to be disconnected from the original mesh while the original mesh stays connected because of what I said above (the game engine needs it).

The way I want to do it is given below:

- bevel the edges
- copy these beveled faces to the clipboard
- undo the bevels
- paste the beveled faces from the clipboard as new mesh

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Did you try duplicating the object, beveling the edges on a copy of the model, and deleting the rest of the unwanted geometry, then merging both meshes?

Comment: Yes I did, and it is slightly better. I wrote this in my original post, but someone improved my post and he was right, it was getting too long and complicated to read. It is indeed a solution, but it's still much more work than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that instead of trying to copy and paste the bevel as a new object, you should simply duplicate the mesh you have, leaving one copy the same, and using the other mesh to create the bevels you wanted.  Simply create the bevels, and with the bevels still selected, hit ctrl-i to invert the selection, and press delete.  This way you end up with just the beveled mesh, yet you still have the original mesh to keep.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As mentioned above (and in my original post but it was getting too complicated so it was removed), I know that that's a solution and it is better, but it's still more work than should be necessary imo. If there is no other option, I will of course do it like that.

Comment: Sorry about that, guess I didn't pay enough attention.  If you wish, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: No... it wasn't meant as a snappy remark. Thanks for your time!